# Cursor not executing compeletely

Tags: mysql

I am using the cursor but out 13 columns, 10 columns are taken but two columns are not taking in the cursor.

for example

This is the values i am fetching by using cursor..but last 3 values are not executing. it stops till 111

```
category_id
123
456
789
111
222
333
444
```

Please help me out of this

Comment: Let me know what would be possible reason

Comment: maybe they are null values ? Also provide some code.

Comment: If i m using those 3 values sepeartely. it is executing one at a time

Comment: Can you share the code which creates the cursor and uses it?